# Why has log4net Info(object, Exception) method

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I wonder why log4net provides the method

```
Info(object message, Exception e)
```

(and of course Warn, Error etc.)

Why is the message parameter not a string? I'd guess that this way it is possible to pass any object and the log message is determined via ToString. But then again, why does the 'ususal' method

```
Info(string message)
```

uses a string and not an object as parameter?

Comment: Yeah, the question is not about the exception but about the log message.

Comment: It does it because log4j does, and log4net is a port of that. You are also mistaken: the [Info method takes an object as a parameter](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_ILog_Info.htm).

Comment: You are right, only the Format methods take a string. I fear the question is obsolete then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log4Net offers [IObjectRenderers](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_ObjectRenderer_IObjectRenderer.htm) which can turn an object in to a string format suitable for logging.

In the case of passing a string then it doesn't need to do anything, in the case of passing other objects it uses an [IObjectRenderer](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_ObjectRenderer_IObjectRenderer.htm).

If the method only took a string then it wouldn't be as flexible.

While there is an [Info(object message)](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_ILog_Info.htm) method, the [ILog](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/AllMembers_T_log4net_ILog.htm) interface doesn't seem to expose an Info(string message) method so I'm not sure where you got that from?

Comment: You had a question, and now you know more about it. I don't think your question is invalid, it's just not the answer you were expecting!